# Postgres check constraint column name

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to list the check constraints for a column in a postgres table. I am using postgres 14.1

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test_change_column (
    address CHARACTER VARYING (200) NOT NULL,
    city CHARACTER VARYING (255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT city_check CHECK ('city' <> 'NYC'),
    country CHARACTER VARYING (255) DEFAULT 'USA',
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT uk_test_change_column_address UNIQUE(address)
);
```

I can get the check constraints for the table using this SQL:

```
SELECT cc.constraint_name, cc.check_clause
FROM information_schema.check_constraints cc 
JOIN information_schema.table_constraints tc ON tc.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
WHERE cc.constraint_schema = 'public' AND tc.table_name = 'test_change_column'
```

If you want to get the column name that the check clause applies I can modify the query to join on constraint_column_usage:

```
SELECT cc.constraint_name, cc.check_clause, ccu.column_name
FROM information_schema.check_constraints cc 
JOIN information_schema.table_constraints tc ON tc.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu ON cc.constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name
WHERE cc.constraint_schema = 'public' AND tc.table_name = 'test_change_column'
```

The joined ccu.column_name column is null.

If I query the underlying pg_constraint table, I still get null in the conkey column:

```
SELECT pgc.conname as constraint_name, pgc.conkey as column_name  
FROM pg_constraint pgc
JOIN pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
JOIN pg_class  cls on pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
WHERE pgc.contype ='c' AND cls.relname = 'test_change_column'
```

Why is conkey null rather than referencing the city column?

Comment: Because you're not using any column in your constraint, you're comparing to character literals: `CHECK ('city' <> 'NYC')`. The information schema list the actual column used in the check expression, not the column it is attached to. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LYRZqYj1)

Comment: city is a column. How should it be referenced in the expression so that conkey is populated?

Comment: As a column name. See the fiddle.

Comment: Ah I see. It's because city is quoted ('city'). thanks.

Comment: You already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75023053